# Upload video to Youtube in multiple threads (.NET SDK)

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-data-api

I have made quick prototype using `youtubeService.Videos.Insert` from `Google.Apis.YouTube.v3`

The only way I can upload is to pass file stream and hope for the best. I would like to upload it in separate threads (eg in Amazon AWS I can split file on chunks and upload them concurrently). Is it possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol#Uploading_Chunks

Comment: "upload them concurrently" I might be wrong, but this seems like an abuse of the chunk upload process. Will uploading concurrently really go faster?

Comment: I will tell when ill have done it. but it boosts considerably pretty much all cloud uploads I worked with. I am talking 100s%

Comment: I cannot find any way to set content range in the .NET SDK..